# The method '[]' was called on null. Receiver: null Tried calling: []("icon")

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-test, fluttermap

I'm trying to solve this problem by changing the code in every way. But don't understand exactly what's the problem here. No matter how i'm changing the code this error is coming at the end. And it shows that my problem in the FutureBuilder .Please, try to help me.

Also check my api json please.

```
{
  "coord": {
    "lon": 90.4167,
    "lat": 24.1667
  },
  "weather": [
    {
      "id": 500,
      "main": "Rain",
      "description": "light rain",
      "icon": "10d"
    }
  ]
}
```

Code example:

```
Widget updateTempWidget(String city) {
  return FutureBuilder(
      future: getWheather(util.appID, city),
      builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasData) {
          Map content = snapshot.data!;
          return Container(
            child: Column(
              children: [
                ListTile(
                  title: Text(content["weather"]["icon"].toString()),
                )
              ],
            ),
          );
        }
        if (snapshot.hasError) {
          return Text("Error");
        }
        return CircularProgressIndicator();
      });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Note that weather is a list and not a map and be careful when using nullable operators, I recommend always mapping the objects from an api to a class checking each object and avoiding using null variables, try to use default values like empty list, empty string, etc.

```
  Widget updateTempWidget(String city) {
    return FutureBuilder(
        future: getWheather(util.appID, city),
        builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasData) {
            var content = snapshot.data ?? {};
            var _weather = content['weather'];
            if(_weather is List){
              var _icon =_weather.isNotEmpty ? (_weather[0]['icon'] ?? 'undefined' ): 'list is empty';
              return Container(
                child: Column(
                  children: [
                    ListTile(
                      title: Text(_icon),
                    )
                  ],
                ),
              );
            }
            return Text("Weather is not list");

          }
          if (snapshot.hasError) {
            return Text("Error");
          }
          return CircularProgressIndicator();
        });
  }
```

Comment: Your code is working. But as you see my api starts with a map, so i'm trying to find a solution in which i can access any of the key value from whole api.

Comment: As I said you must map your json to an object, perform json serialization, as in this [example here](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/data-and-backend/json) from flutter. Without serialization there is no easy way to access objects.

Comment: As said "weather is a list", so to access the first item: content["weather"][0]["icon"].

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should try putting some print statements (or better use debugger) near the line where you retrieve the data.

```
if (snapshot.hasData) {
        Map content = snapshot.data!;
        print(content);
```

Check the object which you are getting and verify that the icon coming from the api is not null.
It will also show you the structure of the data.
You can also directly try logging icon to console

Comment: tried your way but not working. In the debug consule content is printing but now the problem has changes to this --type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'int' of 'index'